# Annotating Exceptions with extra information without catching them

Tags: c#, .net, exception, error-logging

Exceptions sometimes occur.  When they do, they're logged and later analyzed.  The log obviously contains the stack-trace and other global information, but often crucial context is missing.  I'd like to annotate an exception with this extra information to facilitate post-mortem debugging.

- I don't want to `try{...}catch{... throw;}` since that counts as catching an exception and that makes debugging harder (during development I'd like the app to stop and the debugger to react when the original exception is thrown, and not when the outermost uncaught exception is).  First-chance exception handlers aren't a workaround since there are unfortunately too many false positives.
- I'd like to avoid excessive overhead in the normal, non-exceptional case.

Is there any way to store key pieces of context (e.g. filename being processed or whatever) in an exception in a way that doesn't catch the exception?

Comment: Interesting. Have you thought of wrapping the `try{` and `}catch{... throw;}` in `#if !DEBUG`. In dev you'd get the original exception from the original call site.

Comment: How about using the try{..}catch{..throw;} pattern, but change your Visual Studio options to break when a CLR Exception is thrown.

Comment: Seems like a good fit for AOP like PostSharp, but this doesn't meet your requirement of not catching it.  It just removes the amount of coding you need to do.

Comment: Yeah, I _can_ deal with catching it, but it's not ideal at all.  Unfortunately a bunch of API's only have hard failure modes with exceptions (parsing etc.), and setting the debugger to halt on all uncaught exceptions is thus not good.  Instead you might tell the debugger _which_ exceptions to initially ignore; but these are sometimes broad categories like XmlException, and in any case that's a bunch of visual studio configuration that's not in source control and every team member needs to duplicate.  Blech.

Answer (score 1):

I am taking a shot at this building off of Adam's suggestion of Aop.  my solution would be Unity rather than postsharp and the only question I would have is whether the exception is being caught inside of invoke, which it likely is...

```
        public IMethodReturn Invoke(IMethodInvocation input, GetNextInterceptionBehaviorDelegate getNext)
    {
        //execute
        var methodReturn = getNext().Invoke(input, getNext);

        //things to do after execution
        if (methodReturn.Exception != null)
            methodReturn.Exception.Data.Add("filename", "name of file");

        return methodReturn;
    }
}
```

Comment: It's not quite clear to me how normal code leveraging this would look.  So if `A` calls `B` calls `C` and `B` wants to annotate any possible exceptions by `C` with information - how would you use this?

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with the following pattern:

```
try
{
    // Do Something
}
catch (GeneralException ex)
{
    throw new SpecificException(
        String.Format("More specifics ({0}) in message", someData),
        moreContext,
        new {even, more, context},
        ex);
}
```

This is precisely the pattern to use, for instance, when the "Do Something" is to, say, open a file of some kind. The "SpecificException" might be "can't read configuration file".

Comment: The problem here is twofold: first of all, it's generally just clutter, and I'd like to do this systematically. Nested in nested in nested in nested[...] exceptions aren't helping over a simpler flat approach; not to mention that in effect the cost of throwing exceptions can eventually become quadratric with stackdepth this way as opposed to linear.  Secondly, and more immediately annoying, this causes the exception to be caught which complicates debugging as described in the question.

Comment: On second though; it's very unlikely this would result in quadratic time-complexity (though you'd need to know CLR internals to be sure).  However, that does resolve the clutter+debuggability issues.

Comment: Incidentally, this is what I basically do now; it works, but I'm looking for something better :-)

Comment: Just to be clear: I am only talking about doing this in the case where the generic exception would not have been helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I would not use AOP to catch the exceptions. Instead I would use the interception class to LOG  the exception + all arguments to the method that threw the exception. And then let the original exception be thrown again

Comment: -1: bad idea. If the exception doesn't propagate, then you don't capture the entire call stack. Log the exception at the very top, adding additional information near the call site, as the OP requests.

Comment: Why is it a bad idea? Some interception frameworks just `throw;` Call stack is reserved